# Get name of current user

Tags: linux, windows, r, cran

What is a cross-platform way of getting the username of the current user in R? I am currently using

```
system('whoami', intern=TRUE)
```

However this assumes that the user has shell access, and that the `whoami` program is available. Is there a more native to get this information in R?

Comment: Without R How do people do it in windows usually ? I don't have a windows machine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do this :

```
 Sys.getenv("USERNAME")  ## works under windows
```

or better more robust:

```
 Sys.info()[["user"]]
```

But under unix-like system the result is sometimes different of  `system('whoami', intern=TRUE)` :

> whoami outputs the username that the user is working under, whereas
>   $USER outputs the username that was used to login.

For example, if the user logged in as John and su into root, whoami displays root and echo
$USER displays John. This is because the su command does not invoke a
login shell by default.

Comment: This approach supposed that "USERNAME" variable is already set. I'm using Arch Linux and this is not set by default in my setting but "USER" is set. I think the last approach is more robust or `Sys.getenv("USER")`

Comment: IIRC, you can use Sys.info()[["effective_user"]] to get the same output as whoami.

Comment: Perfect! I can't believe I didn't know about `Sys.info`. I searched the manuals for at least 2 minutes! :)